# How To search on a website in WebView?

Tags: java, android, search, browser, webview

I      have     a      WebView     with    a     Search     Bar     but     i     want it to search     on     a    particular     Website.  (search on the website's search bar instead)  can this be done by adding a Prefix? if yes, then how do i do that? any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

package com.Example.test;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private EditText field;
   private WebView browser;

   @Override        
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.urlField);
  browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
  browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
 }


   public void open(View view){
  String url = field.getText().toString();
  browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
  browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
  browser.loadUrl(url);

  }
  private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
     view.loadUrl(url);
     return true;
  }
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
}

}
```

Comment: All you need to know: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: it doesn't have what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First need to add INTERNET permission to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then, use the WebView class to display a web page. First, create a layout that contains a webview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<WebView android:id="@+id/myWebView"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Activity, (probably the onCreate), initialize a WebView object by using the layout you created. An example is below. private WebView webview;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);

  String url = "http://bigdaddyapp.com";

  webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
  //next line explained below
  webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webview.loadUrl(url);
}
```

If you'd like specific options, like catching pages as they load, you need an inner WebViewClient class. For example, you can use the onPageStarted(...) method to do something whenever a new page is loaded in your webview:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

public MyWebViewClient() {
  super();
  //start anything you need to
}

public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
  //Do something to the urls, views, etc.
 }
}
```

Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks